# How to pull out value from Key:Value Pair with Databricks Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

The following code recieves information from Service Bus and prints the information.

```py
def myfunc():
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) as client:
        # max_wait_time specifies how long the receiver should wait with no incoming messages before stopping receipt.
        # Default is None; to receive forever.

          with client.get_queue_receiver(QUEUE_NAME, session_id=session_id, max_wait_time=3600) as receiver:
            for msg in receiver:
                # print("Received: " + str(msg))
                themsg = json.loads(str(msg))
                # complete the message so that the message is removed from the queue
                receiver.complete_message(msg)
                return themsg
```

I then assign a variable to the function as follows:

```
result = myfunc()
```

When I enter the following code

```
result['mappings']
```

I get the following output:

```
Out[45]: [{'ELLIPSE': {'method': 'ellipseItem',
   'tables': [{'database': 'foundation',
     'schema': 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE',
     'table': 'ADS_FND_MSF620',
     'primaryKey': [{'column': 'DSTRCT_CODE', 'seqno': 1},
      {'column': 'WORK_ORDER', 'seqno': 2}]}],
   'columns': [{'column': 'D_WORK_ORDER_KEY',
```

I am now trying to extract 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE' and 'ADS_FND_MSF620'

My attempt is as follows:

```
result['mappings']['table']
```

But I get the Typeerror:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm aware this is simply piece of python code I should know, but any thoughts welcomed

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for editing my question. Any thoughts on an answer?

Comment: Hi all, I have totally revamped the question .. just in case you were helping me prior to the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because list always expects index with integers.
Coming to the error - This error occurs because you have tried to access the dictionary using the key, when the dictionary is inside of a list. If you follow closely then key 'table' is within the dictionary 'ELLIPSE' and it exists at the first index position of the parent list.

Thereby, try accessing the dictionary keys as below -

```
result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['schema']
```

Similarly,

```
result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['table']
```

Comment: Hi Dipsy, thanks for reaching out. You solution didn't appear to work. Therefore, I tried the following: ```result['mappings']['ELLIPSE']['tables']['table']``` but unfortunately, that didn't work either

Comment: You suggestion gave me the following error: 
KeyError: 0

Comment: @Patterson - `[{'ELLIPSE': {'method': 'ellipseItem','tables': [{'database': 'foundation', 'schema': 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE','table': 'ADS_FND_MSF620','primaryKey': [{'column': 'DSTRCT_CODE', 'seqno': 1},
      {'column': 'WORK_ORDER', 'seqno': 2}]}]}}]` I have used this as my list. Does expects anything else?

Comment: May be you have to put the list index 0 after `result['mappings']`. Presumably that should work

Comment: Hi I entered result['mappings'][0] and got the following: ```Out[76]: {'ELLIPSE': {'method': 'ellipseItem',
  'tables': [{'database': 'foundation',
    'schema': 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE',
    'table': 'ADS_FND_MSF620',
    'primaryKey': [{'column': 'DSTRCT_CODE', 'seqno': 1},
     {'column': 'WORK_ORDER', 'seqno': 2}]}],
  'columns': [{'column': 'D_WORK_ORDER_KEY',
    'type': 'BIGINT',``` However, I need to extract 'table' and 'schema'

Comment: Thanks Dipsy for sticking with me on this question. I will try your edited answer in the meantime I executed ```result.items()``` to get all the key-value pairs. Which may help you to help me further ```dict_items([('name', 'dmMapping_DIM_WORK_ORDER'), ('description', 'DIM_WORK_ORDER Azure Foundation to Azure Data Mart Mapping'), ('version', '2.5'), ('updateDttm', '15/02/2022 15:58PM'), ('mappings', [{'ELLIPSE': {'method': 'ellipseItem', 'tables': [{'database': 'foundation', 'schema': 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE', 'table': 'ADS_FND_MSF620', 'primaryKey': [{'column': 'DSTRCT_CODE', ```

Comment: Ahhhhhh ...your edited answer worked. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to combine ```result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['schema']``` with ```result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['table']``` to get AZ_FH_ELLIPSE.ADS_FND_MSF620

Comment: I tried the following ```result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['schema'][0]['table']``` but it didn't work

Comment: @Patterson - This will never work because `schema` is not a list,  and `table` doesn't exists within the `schema` as it is a dictionary key with value `AZ_FH_ELLIPSE`. You'll have to use them independently. You could use a variable of type string then `concat` values from both `schema` as well `table` iteratively.

Comment: ok. so I created two variables ( for schema and table) and tried to combine the two
```schema = result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['schema']``` and ```table = result['mappings'][0]['ELLIPSE']['tables'][0]['table']```
 together as follows: ```my_sales =  spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, schema.table)``` but I get the error ```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'table'```

Comment: It should be used like `my_sales =  spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, '{schema}.{table}'.format(schema=schema, table=table))`

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion, but I got the error ```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'AZ_FH_ELLIPSE.ADS_FND_MSF620'.``` However, when I hardcode it, it works ```my_sales =  spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "AZ_FH_ELLIPSE.AZ_FND_MSF620")```

Comment: oops! I know why it didn't work

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a table called AZ_FND_MSF620 .. When it should be AZ_FND_MSF620

Comment: oh, Dipsy, I nearly forgot to say thank you.